# Listbox Item selection based on other Listbox item selection

Tags: excel, listbox, vba

There two (ActiveX) listboxes on sheet (Monthlist & Yearlist).  Each is populated with unique values from columns H(months) and I(years) (see code below).  The user will select month(s) available in Monthlist.  I would like the available items in ‘Yearlist’ to reflect the selection in ‘Monthlist’. For example, if there is data on sheet for May, 2015 and June, 2016, and the user selects ‘May’ from Monthlist, ‘2015’ should only be available on ‘Yearlist’ for selection. (‘2016’ should be grayed out or not present).

The obvious solution is to apply filter to column H that would reflect the selection in Monthlist, then collect unique visible values from column I into an array and display them in Yearlist. Perhaps there is more elegant solution to this problem? Thanks for your help.

```
    Sub UniqueMonthsAndYears(ByVal ws As Object)

    Dim LastRow, i, j, k As Long
    Dim c As Range
    Dim MyArUniqVal() As Variant

    Dim i2, j2, k2 As Long
    Dim c2 As Range
    Dim MyArUniqVal2() As Variant

    Dim MonthList As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim YearList As MSForms.ListBox

    ReDim MyArUniqVal(0)
    ReDim MyArUniqVal2(0)


    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range


        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

         Set rng = Range("H9:H" & LastRow)

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        For Each cl In rng
            If cl.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then '//Use Hidden property to check if filtered or not
                  Debug.Print cl
                If cl.Value <> cl.Offset(1, 0).Value Then '~~~~~MonthArray

                    MyArUniqVal(UBound(MyArUniqVal)) = cl.Value
                    ReDim Preserve MyArUniqVal(UBound(MyArUniqVal) + 1)
                End If

                If cl.Offset(0, 1).Value <> cl.Offset(1, 1).Value Then 'Year Array
                    MyArUniqVal2(UBound(MyArUniqVal2)) = cl.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    ReDim Preserve MyArUniqVal2(UBound(MyArUniqVal2) + 1)
                End If

           End If
        Next cl

        ReDim Preserve MyArUniqVal(UBound(MyArUniqVal) - 1)
        ReDim Preserve MyArUniqVal2(UBound(MyArUniqVal2) - 1)

    End With

'Fill the listbox
 ws.YearList.Clear

For k2 = 0 To UBound(MyArUniqVal2)

    ws.YearList.AddItem (MyArUniqVal2(k2))

Next k2

ws.MonthList.Clear

For k = 0 To UBound(MyArUniqVal)

    ws.MonthList.AddItem (MyArUniqVal(k))

Next k

End Sub
```